# UserControl as DataTemplate in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol

I am trying to use a `UserControl` as `DataTemplate` in an `ItemsControl`. The `UserControl` is called `WorkItemControl` and the objects in the `ObservableCollection` bound to the `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` is of type `WorkItemModel`.

I get the following error when enabling binding diagnostics

`BindingExpression` path error:

```
'ItemModelText' property not found on 'object' ''WorkItemControl' (Name='')'. 
BindingExpression:Path=ItemModelText; DataItem='WorkItemControl' (Name='');
target element is 'WorkItemControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemText' (type 'String')
```

It works fine if, instead og the UserControl, a Button is used as DataTemplate.`

The following XAML snippet shows the `ItemsControl`.

```
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ItemsControl Name="WorkItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkItemModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <control:WorkItemControl ItemText="{Binding Path=ItemModelText}"/>
                    <!--<Button Content="{Binding Path=ItemModelText}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
```

Any ideas why it won't work with the `UserControl`?

Comment: You are probably setting the DataContext of the WorkItemControl to itself. Then the binding in the DataTemplate will try to find the `ItemModelText` property on the control, not on the data item. So don't set the DataContext of the WorkItemControl when you want to use it in a DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i can write what i think...
You need the RelativeSource=Self to use the UserControl's properties in the UserControl's XAML, but this same RelativeSource gets in the way when you try to bind the properties outside. I'm facing with the same issue. I managed to solve it by setting the source of the outer binding, but i think this is not too elegant way. In fact i think this is a design issue in WPF as (in my thinking) the RelativeSource *inside* the UserControl should not affect any binding *outside* of it (but it does).
If you get this solved a better way, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: ...and i found a solution
Remove the RelativeSource from the UserControl, and add it to its child grid, but not with "Self" parameter, instead this way:
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}}">